# Trying to change timezone and format on a date time column in R

Tags: r, datetime, lubridate, timestamp-with-timezone

I have downloaded some hourly Snotel values, data frame is three columns: dateTime, SWE, and Snow Depth.  The current format from the csv for dateTime is "YYYY-MM-SS HH:MM" and the timezone is MST.  I would like to change the timezone to UTC to match my own data and slightly alter the format to be "YYYY_MM_SS HH:MM:SS".  I have been flailing trying to use as.POSIXct, parse_date_time, as_datetime, and others.  Is there a function I am missing that could do this?

Thanks